# zero delay signal event sequence check

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Supposed that I want to check the change sequence of these two signals: `sigA` and `sigB`. 
The design specification is that `sigB` must change earlier than `sigA` (B change first and then A change)

Here supposed that I have simplified RTL which has a bug with respect to the above specification.

```
// buggy RTL
sigB = ~sigA;
```

In this code, `sigB` change after `sigA` due to inverter delay.

But in RTL, usually, we may not be able to notice the problem - as it is a kind of zero-delay event. 
Only can we realize it in gate-level simulation with a delay that unexpectedly `sigB` actually change slightly later than `sigA`.

I am looking for a way either using SVA or some other method that can detect this issue during RTL simulation rather than detecting it during Gate Level Simulation (which is too late).

Comment: You need more information. Suppose there is no bug and so `sigB` changes before `sigA` as specified. So, your changes will run like this: `sigB change ... sigA change --- sigB change ... sigA change`. In the middle we have `sigA change --- sigB change`. So, `sigB` has changed before `sigA`, but also `sigA` has changed before `sigB`.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is an event driven simulator. It will schedule the execution based on the inputs/outputs of the basic scheduling blocks: `always` and `assign`.

In rtl simulations the sequence of events is defined by sensitivity lists of the `always` blocks or by "inputs" of the `assign` statements. So, the following will behave as you expect:

```
assign sigB = ~sigA;
```

or

```
always @(sigA)
   sibB = ~sigA;
```

The problem will happen if you miss 'sigA' from the sensitivity list of an always block:

```
always @(sigC) 
   sibB = ~sigA;
```

For that reason, veilog 2K came up with the `always @*` statement which does not require you to list all signals in the sensitivity list. So, the following will work correct as well:

```
always @(*)
   sibB = ~sigA;
```

At the end of the simulation tick, the values of all variables will be the same as in the hardware due to the sequence of events in the zero-delay event-driven simulation.